# Sign out Cognito user and revoke Id token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I am building a browser application that connects to AWS IoT using Cognito User Pools for authentication and Identity Pools for federation. I am able to sign in a Cognito user and connect to AWS IoT, but I am having difficulty logging out and preventing access to IoT.

After I call cognitoUser.signOut() I can still use the cached Id tokens to get credentials and connect to AWS IoT. How do I sign a user out so they cannot get credentials and connect to IoT with these tokens?

Answer (score 0):

This should have been fixed on the latest versions of the sdk, but you needed to call clearCachedId(), like this:

AWS.config.credentials.clearCachedId();